# I think i am using JDBC wrong

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Okay so here is my Situation
I have an agenda/calendar app(made with JavaFX).
How it works is that i have 2 MySQL databases on my website.
The Databases are Accounts and Agendas
In the Accounts database  every account has a Username, Password and List of codes fields.
How my agendas work is that you identify every agenda with a UUID code.
The fields for agendas are Code, Name, Creator, Moderators and Data.
Now everything works but it is EXTREMELY slow and since i just got into Database and server programming i am probably doing something wrong because i know MySQL is EXTREMELY fast.

The login function takes about 10 seconds(add 1 second for every agenda a user has). So can anyone help me with this issue?

Account.java http://pastebin.com/kh0i7Cp4

Agenda.java  http://pastebin.com/5RxxV8S2

Login.java

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Stage {
    TextField userTextField;
    PasswordField pwBox;
    public Button acc;

    public Login() {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        setScene(scene);
        this.setTitle("Appgenda");
        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label pw = new Label("Password:");
        grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

        pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);
        Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
        acc = new Button("Create Account");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(acc);
        acc.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new CreateAccount().show();
                close();

            }

        });
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                handleIt();

            }

        });
        show();
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private void handleIt() {
        int login = login(userTextField.getText(), pwBox.getText());
        if (login == 1) {
            // notpass
        } else if (login == 2) {
            // notuser
        } else if (login == 3) {
            // exception or server has no accounts
        } else if (login == 0) {
            // login
            dispose();
        } else {

        }
    }

    private void dispose() {
        close();
    }

    public static int login(String u, String p) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.URL
                    + Global.DATABASE, Global.USERNAME, Global.PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn
                    .prepareStatement("select * from Accounts where Username = '"
                            + u + "'");
            ResultSet x = ps.executeQuery();
            if (x.next()) {
                if (x.getString(2).equals(p)) {
                    // login
                    new JFXPanel();
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                newWindow(x.getString(1));
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });
                    System.out.println("Succesful login");

                    return 0;
                } else {

                    return 1;
                }
            } else {

                return 2;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private static void newWindow(String s) {
        new UserWindow(Account.getAccount(s)).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use `PreparedStatement` with parametrized queries as they are intended to be used instead of concatenating values into your query string. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I am on the fence for closing this as too broad or off topic (eg: better suited for codereview). As I see it there are too many possible reasons, for example `Accounts` having a large number of records and no index on the `Username` column, or connecting taking too long (and on the UI thread by the looks of it, but I don't know JavaFX, so I am not sure), and probably more if I look more closely.

Comment: That didnt help because i dont understand what u are talking about

Comment: Which part? If the current answer solved your initial problem, then please learn how to use `PreparedStatement` correctly, eg see - for a basic introduction - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html Your current way of querying by concatenating values into your query string is highly insecure and the cause of **many security problems**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every database interaction (select, insert, update and delete) you open a new connection and do not close it. Would be better if you could use a database connection pool in order to reuse the connection.

You could initialize the connection pool when your application start and close it when the application were closed.

[Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is a good component to do this job.

There are a lot of topics about jdbc connection pool that you can read and get some good options and tips to increase the performance in your application.

Regards.

Comment: So would you suggest that i Make a global Connection that  i start up in main(string[]) and everytime i make a interaction, i use that one?

Comment: That's a simple way to do it.
Or you can create an util class that handle the database connection and you can have a method that return the connection that is already open.

Comment: how would i go about returning a connection that is already open?

Comment: I made a global connection and DriverManager.getConnection'd it in the main(string[] args) and insted of making a new Connection conn =null; i just used my already set Global connection and it quadrupled startup time... THANK YOU SO MUCH